# Scrapinghub (Scrapy Cloud) - Is there a limit to the number of spiders per project?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline, scrapinghub

I am using **scrapy cloud** to host & run my scrapy project. All seems to work well but when **11th spider** is added to the project, it doesn't show up in the scrapinghub dashboard.

I know this should be a rather simple thing to find out but it isn't written anywhere.

Before dividing up my project for every 10 spiders, I would like to know

1. If there is any limit of spiders per project?
2. If there is a way to increase the limit as I will be dealing with a lot of spiders with same pipeline.

Comment: Is there any chance you have 2 spiders with the same name?

Comment: @Gallaecio no all spiders have a unique name which is the same as their website. Actually the matter has been resolved by their support now. The dropdown which shows all spiders has an odd behaviour and shows only top 10 spiders alhpabatically. For rest you have to type their name in.